# c# TCP NetworkStream is not receiving data

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send files after sending their's information via TCP connection. At the end of receiver host, the data packets are received. I used Wireshark to confirm it. However the data couldn't be received in `NetworkStream`.

```
public class FileTransporter
{
    public void ReceiveFiles(IPAddress IP, int port)
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IP, port);
        tcpListener.Start();
        using (TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
        {
            if (tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                using (NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    int pointer = 0;
                    byte[] fileNameLengthBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
                    networkStream.Read(fileNameLengthBytes, pointer, fileNameLengthBytes.Length);
                    int fileNameLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileNameLengthBytes, pointer);

                    // code to read fileName and it's size

                    networkStream.Close();
                }
            }
            tcpClient.Close();
        }
        tcpListener.Stop();
    }

    public void SendFiles(IPAddress IP, int port, string[] paths)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<paths.Length; i++)
        {
            FilePackage filePackage = new FilePackage(paths[i]);
            byte[] infoBytes = filePackage.EncodeInfoToByte();
            using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                tcpClient.Connect(IP, port);
                using (NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    networkStream.Write(infoBytes, 0, infoBytes.Length);
                    networkStream.Close();
                }
                tcpClient.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class FilePackage
{
    public FilePackage(string fileName)
    {
        this.Info = new FileInfo(fileName);
    }

    public byte[] EncodeInfoToByte()
    {
        List<byte> infoByte = new List<byte>();

        infoByte.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(this.Info.Name.Length));
        infoByte.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.Info.Name));

        infoByte.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(this.Info.Length));

        return infoByte.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to Assume that ReadFiles is invoked somehow / somewhere else.

I have a very similar implementation, however my "Read" of the stream is much smaller:

```
// Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            var bytes = new byte[512];
            // Loop to receive all the data sent by the Server.
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            do
            {
                var i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i));
            } while (stream.DataAvailable);
```

Perhaps using "stream.DataAvailable" will allow you to test for data existence and that way you can make sure that you only process when data is available.

Also I don't see where "pointer" is being initialized in your code.
If it is not set to 0 each time, you will not be processing from the beginning of the data packet.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably being caused by the nagle algorithm, prevent small amounts of data being sent to reduce congestion. You could try disabling it by setting the following properties on your tcpClient

tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
tcpClient.Client.NoDelay = true